# How to insert picture into special part of word?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a picture of internet . I want save it in special part of word .

I find special part with this code .

```
  XNamespace w =
          "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
        XNamespace r =
            "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships";


        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;
        XDocument mainDocumentXDoc = GetXDocument(wordDoc);
        var q1 = mainDocumentXDoc
        .Root
        .Element(w + "body")
        .Elements();

        // project collection of tuples containing element and type
        var q2 = q1
            .Select(s =>
            {
                string keyForGroupAdjacent = ".NonContentControl";
                if (s.Name == w + "sdt")
                    keyForGroupAdjacent = (s.Element(w + "sdtPr").Element(w + "tag") != null) ? s.Element(w + "sdtPr").Element(w + "tag").Attribute(w + "val").Value : "";
                if (s.Name == w + "sectPr")
                    keyForGroupAdjacent = null;
                return new
                {
                    Element = s,
                    KeyForGroupAdjacent = keyForGroupAdjacent
                };
            }
            ).Where(s => s.KeyForGroupAdjacent != null);



            foreach (var item in q2)
        {
            if (item.Element.Value == "[متن]")
            {
                item.Element.AddFirst(**Picture**);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Who do add this picture in item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find :)

I search imagepart with  name (Picture 1 ). Then replace my new picture with old picture .

```
  IEnumerable<Blip> Blips = from run in mainPart.Document.Descendants<Drawing>()
                                      where
                                         run.Descendants<Inline>().First() != null
                                         &&
                                         run.Descendants<Inline>().First().DocProperties.Name != null
                                      &&
                                      run.Descendants<Inline>().First().DocProperties.Name.ToString() == "Picture 1"
                                      select run.Descendants<Blip>().First();
            string imageId = "default value";

            if (Blips != null || Blips.Count() > 0)
            {
                imageId = Blips.First().Embed.Value;
                ImagePart imagePart1 = (ImagePart)mainPart.GetPartById(imageId);
                imagePart1.FeedData(stream);
            }
```